# error C2084: function 'float cbrt(float) throw()' already has a body

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I successfully complied this project under the platform of visual studio 2010,but in vs 2013 has occured these errors:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(1045) : see previous definition of 'cbrt'
d:\documents\qtprojecttest\rtsc\project4\trimesh2\include\Vec.h(657) : error C2084: function 'long double cbrt(long double) throw()' already has a body
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(1161) : see previous definition of 'cbrt'
d:\documents\qtprojecttest\rtsc\project4\trimesh2\include\Vec.h(664) : error C2084: function 'float round(float) throw()' already has a body
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(1125) : see previous definition of 'round'
d:\documents\qtprojecttest\rtsc\project4\trimesh2\include\Vec.h(672) : error C2084: function 'long double round(long double) throw()' already has a body
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(1241) : see previous definition of 'round'
d:\documents\qtprojecttest\rtsc\project4\trimesh2\include\Vec.h(679) : error C2084: function 'float trunc(float) throw()' already has a body
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(1143) : see previous definition of 'trunc'
d:\documents\qtprojecttest\rtsc\project4\trimesh2\include\Vec.h(687) : error C2084: function 'long double trunc(long double) throw()' already has a body
```

I want to know why there is such a difference,and how to solve it ?

Comment: Seems there is a conflict between standard maths and `Vec.h`.  Do you redefine standard function there ?  have you an include guard ?  Or do you include inside your own namespace ?

Comment: You basically discovered why Microsoft avoided supporting C99 for so long.  It dumps a bunch of short common names into the global namespace, very hard to deal with.  But they could not avoid it any longer, C++11 demands it.  So, roughly, your own workaround for missing C99 functions is no longer appropriate.  Remove them.  The Output window says where they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

why there is such a difference about VS2010 and VS2013 ? Because VS2010 doesn't have define of "cbrt",but Vs2013 have.So you can use _MSC_VER , or directly comment repeat function body in Vec.h.